# SVG curve to many small straight lines

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am not using d3.js. I would like to know if there is currently any JS library that can help to convert any curved line in SVG path to many small lines with precision specified. An example of a path to convert would be:
    `<path d="M0 50 a50 50 0 1 0 100 0 a50 50 0 1 0 -100 0">`

Example of results would be to convert 
[this circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Kgi.jpg), into [this n-gon that looks almost like a circle](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/Regular_polygon_12_annotated.svg/220px-Regular_polygon_12_annotated.svg.png). Apologise for lack of good examples as I really do not know how to convert a curve to multiple small straight lines.

Comment: This is generally known as "flattening". Use that term in your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you don't need a library for that. SVG has two DOM APIs for paths: `getTotalLength` and `getPointAtLength`. With these two it's simple to do what you want.

just devide the total length of the path by the num of segments you want, and then walk along the path with these steps using getPointAtLenght to get the points for your line segments.

```js
flatten(src1,5)
flatten(src2,7)
flatten(src3,11)
flatten(src4,100)

function flatten(path,num){
  var l = path.getTotalLength()
  var p = path.getPointAtLength(0)
  var d = `M${p.x} ${p.y}`
  for(var i = (l/num);i<=l;i+=(l/num)){
    p = path.getPointAtLength(i)
    d+=`L${p.x} ${p.y}`
  }
  path.setAttribute("d",d+"z")
}
```

```html
<svg width="800" height="200" viewBox="0 0 800 200" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5">
  <path id="src1" d="M100 10 A90 90 0 0 0 100 190A90 90 0 0 0 100 10z"/>
  <path transform="translate(200 0)" id="src2" d="M100 10 A90 90 0 0 0 100 190A90 90 0 0 0 100 10z"/>
  <path transform="translate(400 0)" id="src3" d="M100 10 A90 90 0 0 0 100 190A90 90 0 0 0 100 10z"/>
  <path transform="translate(600 0)" id="src4" d="M100 10 A90 90 0 0 0 100 190A90 90 0 0 0 100 10z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Cool answer....

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it!